# Only Excel Splash Screen Visible after Launch while VB is Running

Tags: excel, vba

Of the many reports I've creating in Excel VBA, I've got one report that normally launches from a scheduler with a countdown timer that will pull external data, email, then automatically close if the user doesn't press a stop button before the query process begins.  I've only inserted some code that clears all cell contents and formats on the worksheet where I once had formulas and conditional formatting.  After saving the report, then launching by file association as before, now only the Excel splash screen is visible while VBA runs in the background.  If I insert an "Exit Sub" anywhere in any procedure that runs, from beginning to end in the code prior to the "quit" call, the application becomes visible when the code stops.  It opens normally if Excel is already open.  I've found that even if I manually delete the cell contents and clear formatting and save the report on a working copy of the report, it does the same thing.  At no time do I hide sheets, workbook, or application. I've only found it runs normally on my own personal PC Win7-64 and Excel 2016.  None of the systems report an error in the workbook.

I've tried the following without results on our business network servers and Citrix Desktops with a variety of OS's and Excel versions:

1. Application visible
2. Foreground
3. Windows visible
4. Workbook visible
5. Worksheet visible
6. Deleting the sheet and writing data to the new sheet
7. Manually deleting the cell contents and formats on a working version
8. Re-creating the report from scratch with the same code, but it still does the same thing.
9. Excel 2010 and 2016
10. 32 and 64-bit versions of Excel
11. Operating Systems - Windows 7, 10, Server 2016

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: It would be quite helpful to see some code. [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

When a macro is long in VBA, or the task then the display starts to flicker. I think you have the same issue. So, if this is the issue then try to set the screen update off in your VBA.
To do so, go to your macro and type this code i.e.-
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Just confirm, if its helping.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an ugly workaround. I've created a sub to call on workbook_open(). It first makes the application invisible, opens a new workbook, closes the new workbook, then makes the application visible again.